# Ambiguous regexp literal hounds error in then clause cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber

```
Then /I see overlap exception/ do
  error_div = find('.alert')
  error_div.has_content? 'Capacity Commitment can not overlap other period'
end
```

Hounds thrown error as below:

Ambiguous regexp literal. Parenthesize the method arguments if it's surely a regexp literal, or add a whitespace to the right of the / if it should be a division.

I use  cucumber features/account_management/participant_accounts.feature --strict but no error found and test passed successfully.

Comment: `Then(/I see overlap exception/)  do` would resolve this issue with hounds, but I would recommend just skip this bark.

Comment: Have a look at this --- http://www.rubydoc.info/github/bbatsov/rubocop/Rubocop/Cop/Lint/AmbiguousRegexpLiteral

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to use a specific format for the string match:

```
Then /^I see overlap text$/ do
  error_div = find('.alert')
  error_div.has_content? 'Capacity Commitment can not overlap other period'
end
```